# How to make this segue animation exit to right or left side? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swipe

This code works fine to make my custom segue transition with a downwards animation. How would I make the animation look as if it is transitioning to the left or right?

Also - I am using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to trigger the segue. It works fine except that the segue occurs as soon as I do the smallest swipe. How would I allow the segue to not occur untill a user has lifted their finger off or atleast done a larger swipe. Would I need to use a scrollView for this?

Below is my code for my UISwipeGestureRecognizer.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var swipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showSecondViewController")
    swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)

}
```

**The code below is my animation code**

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    // Animate the transition.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in

                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                        animated: false,
                        completion: nil)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Animation Direction**

You will simply need to change the initial and destination frames. Currently the `secondVCView`'s initial frame's X,Y origin `0.0`, `screenHeight`, meaning it sits just below the bottom of the screen. If you want it to appear from the right you would need to change it to `screenWidth`, `0.0`.

Then the destination frame of `firstVCView` would change so the origin is `-screenWidth`, `0.0` and the destination frame of `secondVCView` would change so the origin is `0.0`, `0.0`

```
override func perform() {

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    // Animate the transition.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in

                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                        animated: false,
                        completion: nil)
            }
    }
}
```

**Delayed swipe**

Modify your `showSecondViewController` method to accept a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` parameter and inspect it's `state` property. If you want to trigger the segue when the user has lifted their finger trigger the segue when the `state` is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

If you want more fine grained control such as when they have swiped a certain distance you will need to check the state for `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and monitor the location of the touch. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader as there are plenty of examples a quick Google search away :)